# displaying a crystal report using c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report

I am relatively new to C# and i have never used Crystal Reports so i apologise if i do use the incorrect terminology. I am trying to display a report which is called by some C# code. By following a lot of threads on here, i have managed to come up with the following code which does build an debug. However, when the code is run, it does not display the report.

Here is the code:

```
private void forAllQualitiesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    CrystalReportViewer rv = new CrystalReportViewer();
    string reportPath = @"C:\Documents and Settings\rp\Desktop\StockByStatus.rpt"; 

    ReportDocument r = new ReportDocument();

    r.Load(reportPath);
    rv.Visible = false; // i put this in because when i ran the code without it, it said the report must not be visible and the program would fall down
    rv.ReportSource = r;
    rv.InitReportViewer();
    ShowDialog(rv);
}
```

Comment: I dealt with SAP for a about 6 weeks trying to get some crystal reports stuff working stably under .NET 4.5. When I continued to have problems and suggested that our company might be better off going with SSRS, SAP's tech support agreed that would probably be a better solution for us. Crystal is the red-headed step-child at SAP. The support is terrible. Unless your company already dumps huge sums into SAP's pocket, you too might be better off with a better supported solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
    cryRpt.Load(@"CRYSTAL REPORT PATH HERE\CrystalReport1.rpt");
    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
    crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void forAllQualitiesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

                    {
                        CrystalReportViewer rv = new CrystalReportViewer();
                        doc = new ReportDocument();
                        doc.Load(Server.MapPath("MR.rpt"));
                        doc.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "Admin123", "vivek", "PURCHASE", false);
                        reportdocument.SetParameterValue("@MRNO", ddlmrno.SelectedValue);
                        rv .ReportSource = doc;
                    }
```

Now 
Try this code as reference code....

Comment: thanks for the response. I shouldve added that this is for c#.net. So i dont think that this would work as i do not have any aspx files in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Its Better you add windows form and drag and drop Crystel report viwer to form.It's automatically set as full screen.thart report viwer you can used view all crystel reports in your Application.***Note:You need to install Crystel report run time compatible version according our Visual studio version.***

[image]

Now you can call to report like this in Button press event

```
 private void btOPdetailRep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   try
  {
    load();
    frmReports.printproparty = 7;   //7 what i assign numer for identify report
    frmReports objshow = new frmReports();
    objshow.ShowDialog();
  }
    catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Details Printing Error!");
  }
}
```

then in report form loading event write this code

```
string username = "sa";       //USERNAME AND PASSWORD FOR REPORT LOADING
 string password = "123";
if (printproparty == 7)
  {
   ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
   cryRpt.Load(@"op payment.rpt");
   cryRpt.SetDatabaseLogon(username, password);
   reports.ReportSource = cryRpt;
   reports.RefreshReport();
   reports.Refresh();
  }
```