# Crystal Report Generation

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cancel_Admission_Report car = new Cancel_Admission_Report();
        car.Load("//Cancel_Admission_Rpt.rpt");
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = car;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();


    }
```

Error at (car."Load")   The event 'System.Windows.Forms.Form.Load' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Comment: Are you sure that `Cancel_Admission_Report` is the right class? It looks like you have a form called that. Maybe it's in a different namespace?

Comment: yeah it is... Cancel_Admission_Report is the right class

Answer (score 0):

[Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an event of [System.Windows.Forms.Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. You can not use this as method. This is the reason why you get the message that you can only use the `+=` and `-=` operators with the `car.Load` on the left side.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: report using crystal report.

Comment: Have a look here if you want to load a report: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218371/displaying-a-crystal-report-using-c-sharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218371/displaying-a-crystal-report-using-c-sharp)